# Textarea count characters not working as needed

Tags: javascript

I have simple script character counter, but i cannot understand why it's showing that it's 5 or any other number less than 10, as remaining characters.It must show that it's "0" characters remaining and also it's not counting if i paste some text into text area. How can i fix this?

**HTML CODE**

```
<textarea name="" id="txtarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

**JS CODE**

```
var txt = document.getElementById("txtarea");
txt.setAttribute("maxlength", 50)
var maxLength = 50;
var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
var checkLength = function(){
    if(txt.value.length < maxLength) {
        var result = demo.innerHTML =  " Character remaining: " + (maxLength-txt.value.length) 
    };  
};
setInterval(checkLength, 300);
```

Comment: if(txt.value.length <= maxLength)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem: `if(txt.value.length < maxLength)`

Should be:  `if(txt.value.length <= maxLength)`

Anyway, I wouldn't do it with a time interval but on the [keyDown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown) event. Something like this:

```js
var txt = document.getElementById("txtarea");
txt.setAttribute("maxlength", 50)
var maxLength = 50;
var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
var checkLength = function(){
    if(txt.value.length <= maxLength) {
        var result = demo.innerHTML =  " Character remaining: " + (maxLength-txt.value.length) 
    };  
};
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="txtarea" cols="30" onKeyDown="checkLength()" rows="10"></textarea>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Oh Thank You so much, so basic mistake)

Answer (score 1):

One, as @jolmos said, you have to check if it is less or EQUAL to. You are just checking if this is less than so it will never show "0" as remaining characters number.

Two, about that not counting when paste try to bind this `checkLength()` function to keyup/keydown event instead of calling it from interval.

Try this:

```
txt.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
if(txt.value.length <= maxLength) {
    var result = demo.innerHTML =  " Character remaining: " + (maxLength-txt.value.length) 
};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you type fast it will never show 4 or 5 characters remaining. A better solution would be to put an `onchange` event on it. And yes, it should be `<=` :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that it should be `txt.value.length <= maxLength` this should be working perfectly fine (check out this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Aides/nc39hsng/)

Also you might use `onkeyup` and `onchange` instead of `setInterval`